# Fetching API-Key from JSON file

Tags: firebase, api-key

The API key for my project is stored inside a JSON file. When I fetch the key and log it to the console, the correct API key appears. However, when I assign the value to a variable and use that variable where the API key should be located, I encounter an error message.
WHich sais that the API-Key is not valid.

I have confirmed that the API key is accurate by logging it to the console, so there shouldn't be any issues with the key itself.

The code snippet I'm using to fetch the JSON file and retrieve the API key is as follows:

```js
let apiKey;
fetch('server.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    apiKey = data.apiKey;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching server.json:', error);
  });

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: "************",
  databaseURL: "****************",
  projectId: "************",
  storageBucket: "****************",
  messagingSenderId: "********",
  appId: "************",
  measurementId: "************"
};
```

The structure of the server.json file is as follows:

```json
{
  "apiKey": "your-api-key"
}
```